# Django Customize PasswordResetView: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I try to customize Django [PasswordResetView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView) in order to validate the length of the password  but I get this error:

```
TypeError at /accounts/password_reset/
__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'
```

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

class PasswordResetView(auth_views.PasswordResetView):
    form_class = PasswordResetForm
    template_name = "accounts/users/password_reset.html"
    email_template_name = "accounts/users/password_reset_email.html"
    subject_template_name = "accounts/users/password_reset_subject.txt"
    from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
    success_url = reverse_lazy("accounts_password_reset_done")
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import SetPasswordForm

class PasswordResetForm(SetPasswordForm):

    def clean_new_password1(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data.get("new_password1")
        if len(password) < 12:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Password must be at least 12 characters.")
        return password
```

It is obvious that [SetPasswordForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.SetPasswordForm) class needs to be taken user upon initialization:

```
class SetPasswordForm(forms.Form):
   . . .
    
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = user
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

I do not find a clear solution to how to pass `user` data to `PasswordResetView` and `PasswordResetForm` because user data is used upon `PasswordResetForm` instance creation.

Comment: The `SetPasswordForm` is used in the `PasswordResetConfirmView` view, not the `PasswordResetView`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SetPasswordForm` is used in the <s>`PasswordResetConfirmView`</s> view, not the `PasswordResetView`. In the `PasswordResetConfirmView`, the [**`get_form_kwargs()`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form_kwargs) is [overridden with <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.1/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L85-L88):

> ```
> def get_form_kwargs(self):
>     kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
>     kwargs['user'] = self.user
>     return kwargs
> ```

You thus likely should subclass the `PasswordResetConfirm` view, and work with the `PasswordResetForm` form for the `PasswordResetView`.

Comment: Wow! What a quick response and an accurate answer. I always appreciate your answers on SO and contributions to the Django community. I'm really thankful for your effort.